# Explanation of macros in javascript from struct.js

Tags: javascript, macros

I know javascript but I don't understand the code in [struct.js](https://github.com/jlongster/struct.js/blob/master/src/macros.js) git repo. Does it  use ES6? Can anyone explain the macros from that code and where can I find more information about it?

The code look like this:

```
let function = macro {
    case { _ $id $args { $expr ... } } => {
        var SP = makeIdent('SP', #{$name});
        return withSyntax($SP = [SP]) {
            return #{
                function $id $args {
                    var $prevSP = $SP;
                    $expr ...
                    $SP = $prevSP;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That code don't work on Chromium (v. 30 on Xubuntu) I've also try to run it on node v0.10.22. Where can I test this code?

Comment: *"Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — **in the question itself**."*

Comment: Are we supposed to search this repository to find where the macro system is defined ? I wouldn't expect this from a user with almost 10k rep.

Comment: -1 you should know by now

Comment: @dystroy It's 100 lines of code, do you want to copy past the code to the question?

Comment: @jcubic As you seem to be new here, please have a look at http://sscce.org

Comment: BTW, this is the laziest question... From the short readme of the project you linked to : *"This is all possible today in JavaScript with a few sweet.js macros."*.

Comment: Before of open the question, is better that you studying the code.
After open this question and explain what is the specific problem with specific code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That code uses a preprocessor to convert from [`sweet.js`](http://sweetjs.org/) to Javascript.

It's not bare Javascript.